# How can you handle orientation change with UIScrollView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, orientation

I have a horizontal scroll view containing two pages as seen pictured here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kamhe.jpg

When I open this view in portrait or landscape mode it renders just fine. However, whenever I switch orientation, the constraints on the scroll view misalign as pictured here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEN7x.jpg

Here are the relevant constraints:

```
info1.anchor(top: Hscroll.topAnchor, left: Hscroll.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 150)

info2.anchor(top: Hscroll.topAnchor, left: info1.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 150)

Hscroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width*2, height: 150)
```

Is there anyway to handle this?